# does file download using PHP, causes server/CPU overload?

Tags: php, load-balancing

On one of my site, I have a large-file download method using:

```
site.com/downloader.php?file=MyLargeFile.mp3
```

then PHP file executes `readfile` to start file downloading.

Typically, not to go in details of load-balancing, I just wanted to know how PHP engine works - does such approach in PHP  (throwing files using`readfile`, `file_get_contents` or etc...) take more CPU/Overload, compared to downloading with direct links, like `site.com/MyLargeFile.mp3`? Or PHP engine does same using those commands?

Comment: Yes, there will be a significant difference. Php is slow like hell.

Comment: Contrary to the above comment and the answer received, I seriously doubt that such a script could cause your overload.  It will obviously use more resources than a direct download but there is probably something else that's causing your issue.  Did you check `top` or at the very least, your web server log?

Comment: thanks for response. I will try `top`. Also, I have found this topic too: http://www.tecmint.com/command-line-tools-to-monitor-linux-performance/

Comment: Obvious is to simply measure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to know for sure without more information. You need to check and see what's causing the high CPU usage, not ask. The `top` command will probably be a good start. We need you to gather some info and show us your script too possibly if you need help with it.

Otherwise it's just a guess and my guess is: yes direct file access is less likely to impact server performance. But your script and web config could be fine. There's no way to know. The problem could be something completely different.